# 3V triggered switch using an IC

Tags: led, operational-amplifier, dc

I have, what I'm sure, is an absurdly simple question:

How do I step up 3 volts to 5 volts using either an OP_Amp or an XOR IC?

Background:

- I have a 5volt power supply.
- I have a 3volt output from a motion detector (which is supplied by the aforementioned 5volts) .. I have a 5volt circuit that needs to be triggered when the motion detector is tripped (which would, presumably, also be supplied by the aforementioned 5volts).
- Currently, I'm using an exclusive OR GATE IC to grab the 3V output from the switch .. I had hoped that this would then pass-through the 5V from Vcc through to the waiting 5V circuit on the opposite end of the circuit.

Additional info:
 - XOR IC : CD74HCT86 74HCT86 QUAD 2-INPUT EXCLUSIVE OR GATE
 - IR Motion Sensor : HC-SR501 IR Pyroelectric Infrared PIR Motion Sensor
 - Circuit needing voltage : array of LED lights.

Let me know if you need additional info.

Answer (score 5):

This is normally done by a **level shifter** but you don't need one. The 74HCT series is an HCMOS series compatible with TTL (hence the "T"). This means it will work with the TTL values for the minimum for a high input level, which is 2 V. So the 3 V output from the PIR is sufficiently high to be seen as a high level by the 74HCT86.

*Odd, a 5 V device with a 3.3 V output, but it's also mentioned on Amazon...*

Comment: thanks for the wicked fast response .. 
what of it i was able to understand leads me to believe that i have headed down the right path .. thing is .. it doesn't work.
i've built a tiny board with 5v going into the 78HCT86 and the 3V trigger from the IR IC .. i'm not getting anywhere near 5V on the output side of the 74HCT86. ... 
any ideas?
is it possible that i need a completely separate power supply for the IR IC and the switch?

thanks in advance.

Comment: "Not anywhere near 5 V" sounds weird for a digital IC. It should be either 5 V or 0 V. Is the power supply indeed 5 V? What have you connected to the output?

Comment: Power supply is a standard USB charger for an IPOD. Tested with .. an IPOD and a multi-meter.

Comment: @bil - So that's the power supply for the 74HCT86? And you measure 5 V at the Vcc pin? How much does the output give? and with nothing connected? (I want to know what's with the *"not getting anywhere near 5V on the output"*.)

Comment: the 5V supply powers both the IR sensor and 74HCT86. i've measured 5V going into the IR sensor and at Vcc of the 74HCT86. what i'm wondering is if i need a completely separate power supply (i'm pretty new to electricity .. computer programmer by trade) for the Vcc once the IR has been triggered.
i confess that i've not (it just occurred to me to do so) tested the 'remaining' voltage once the IR sensor has been tripped. i suppose that it's possible that the 'available' voltage at Vcc is less than the 5V present before the IR sensor gets (thank you so much for your help, by the way) tripped.

Comment: @bil - no you don't need separate supplies. The 74HCT86 will see anything between 2 V and 5 V on its input as a high level, so the PIR's 3.3 V output falls within that range so that should be OK. Connect the PIR's output to an XOR gate input, and make the other input high (+5 V). The output of the XOR gate should now be the inverse of the PIR's output. If you connect the second input to ground instead of +5 V you should see high out when input high. I.e. 3.3 V input should be 5 V output.

Comment: excellent .. i'll give it a shot tonight. you've been tremendously helpful. if you ever should have any programming/database questions, i'm at your disposal.